# Subclassing UISegmentedControl to add a colored UIView on each segment

Tags: iphone, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to add a little colored indicator (just a colored rectangle) to a UISegmentedControl.  I thought I could subclass UISegmentedControl and add that flag in initWithFrame like this:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        UIColor *first = [UIColor blueColor];
        UIColor *second = [UIColor orangeColor];

        UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x + 5, self.bounds.origin.y + 5, 10, self.bounds.size.height)];
        firstView.backgroundColor = first;

        [self addSubview:firstView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When I instantiate a CustomSegmentedControl object, I just get the blue rectangle, but none of the other original segmentedcontrol drawing logic.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal,

is it possible to use an image for the colored rectangle? If so, you could use

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```

to add the image. Something like

```
[segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blueRectangle"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It is possible to set an image for the colored rectangle. I have the same issue but I'm trying to get away from using a whole set .pngs. I'm about to subclass as well.